# password manager and key management

Tags: encryption, passwords, password-management

I would love to gather some information on how to program my own password manager properly as I'm pretty new to security. Currently, I'm using pythons cryptography module and a sqlite database.

The data in the database is encrypted with [MultiFernet](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/fernet/) using a fernet key and a [PBKDF2HMAC](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/primitives/key-derivation-functions/#cryptography.hazmat.primitives.kdf.pbkdf2.PBKDF2HMAC) key (created by password + salt). Except of the master passwords salt which is only encrypted with the fernet key and also stored in the database.

The fernet key is not encrypted in any way (while it's not part of the database nor in the same directory) - should there be a third key to encrypt it as well?

What's the usual workflow on securing keys? At the moment I'm preferably storing them on USB sticks.

Comment: There are different approaches based on specific threat models on how to design a password manager. I would recommend reading through the security decisions done by the Bitwarden team, and seeing if they make sense for your particular threat model: https://bitwarden.com/images/resources/security-white-paper-2021.pdf

Comment: Bitwarden is open-source, so you might also want to check its implementation: https://github.com/bitwarden